# Dataframe merge creates duplicate records in pandas (0.7.3)

Tags: merge, duplicates, pandas

When I merge two CSV files, of the format (date, someValue), I see some duplicate records.

*If I reduce the records to half the problem goes away. However, if I double the size of both the files it worsens. Appreciate any help!*

#### My code:

```
i = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('i.csv')
i = i.reset_index()
e = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('e.csv')
e = e.reset_index()

total_df = pd.merge(i, e, right_index=False, left_index=False,
                    right_on=['date'], left_on=['date'], how='left')
total_df = total_df.sort(column='date')
```

(Note: the dupulicate records for 11/15, 11/16, 12/17, 12/18.)

```
In [7]: total_df
Out[7]:
                  date  Cost  netCost
25 2012-11-15 00:00:00     1        2
26 2012-11-15 00:00:00     1        2
31 2012-11-16 00:00:00     1        2
32 2012-11-16 00:00:00     1        2
37 2012-11-17 00:00:00     1        2
2  2012-11-18 00:00:00     1        2
5  2012-11-19 00:00:00     1        2
8  2012-11-20 00:00:00     1        2
11 2012-11-21 00:00:00     1        2
14 2012-11-22 00:00:00     1        2
17 2012-11-23 00:00:00     1        2
20 2012-11-24 00:00:00     1        2
23 2012-11-25 00:00:00     1        2
29 2012-11-26 00:00:00     1        2
35 2012-11-27 00:00:00     1        2
0  2012-11-28 00:00:00     1        2
3  2012-11-29 00:00:00     1        2
6  2012-11-30 00:00:00     1        2
9  2012-12-01 00:00:00     1        2
12 2012-12-02 00:00:00     1        2
15 2012-12-03 00:00:00     1        2
18 2012-12-04 00:00:00     1        2
21 2012-12-05 00:00:00     1        2
24 2012-12-06 00:00:00     1        2
30 2012-12-07 00:00:00     1        2
36 2012-12-08 00:00:00     1        2
1  2012-12-09 00:00:00     2        2
4  2012-12-10 00:00:00     2        2
7  2012-12-11 00:00:00     2        2
10 2012-12-12 00:00:00     2        2
13 2012-12-13 00:00:00     1        2
16 2012-12-14 00:00:00     2        2
19 2012-12-15 00:00:00     2        2
22 2012-12-16 00:00:00     2        2
27 2012-12-17 00:00:00     1        2
28 2012-12-17 00:00:00     1        2
33 2012-12-18 00:00:00     1        2
34 2012-12-18 00:00:00     1        2
```

#### i.csv

```
date,Cost
2012-11-15 00:00:00,1
2012-11-16 00:00:00,1
2012-11-17 00:00:00,1
2012-11-18 00:00:00,1
2012-11-19 00:00:00,1
2012-11-20 00:00:00,1
2012-11-21 00:00:00,1
2012-11-22 00:00:00,1
2012-11-23 00:00:00,1
2012-11-24 00:00:00,1
2012-11-25 00:00:00,1
2012-11-26 00:00:00,1
2012-11-27 00:00:00,1
2012-11-28 00:00:00,1
2012-11-29 00:00:00,1
2012-11-30 00:00:00,1
2012-12-01 00:00:00,1
2012-12-02 00:00:00,1
2012-12-03 00:00:00,1
2012-12-04 00:00:00,1
2012-12-05 00:00:00,1
2012-12-06 00:00:00,1
2012-12-07 00:00:00,1
2012-12-08 00:00:00,1
2012-12-09 00:00:00,2
2012-12-10 00:00:00,2
2012-12-11 00:00:00,2
2012-12-12 00:00:00,2
2012-12-13 00:00:00,1
2012-12-14 00:00:00,2
2012-12-15 00:00:00,2
2012-12-16 00:00:00,2
2012-12-17 00:00:00,1
2012-12-18 00:00:00,1
```

#### e.csv

```
date,netCost
2012-11-15 00:00:00,2
2012-11-16 00:00:00,2
2012-11-17 00:00:00,2
2012-11-18 00:00:00,2
2012-11-19 00:00:00,2
2012-11-20 00:00:00,2
2012-11-21 00:00:00,2
2012-11-22 00:00:00,2
2012-11-23 00:00:00,2
2012-11-24 00:00:00,2
2012-11-25 00:00:00,2
2012-11-26 00:00:00,2
2012-11-27 00:00:00,2
2012-11-28 00:00:00,2
2012-11-29 00:00:00,2
2012-11-30 00:00:00,2
2012-12-01 00:00:00,2
2012-12-02 00:00:00,2
2012-12-03 00:00:00,2
2012-12-04 00:00:00,2
2012-12-05 00:00:00,2
2012-12-06 00:00:00,2
2012-12-07 00:00:00,2
2012-12-08 00:00:00,2
2012-12-09 00:00:00,2
2012-12-10 00:00:00,2
2012-12-11 00:00:00,2
2012-12-12 00:00:00,2
2012-12-13 00:00:00,2
2012-12-14 00:00:00,2
2012-12-15 00:00:00,2
2012-12-16 00:00:00,2
2012-12-17 00:00:00,2
2012-12-18 00:00:00,2
```

Comment: Can you upgrade to `0.10.0`?  I can't reproduce your problem with it, anyway.

Comment: This looks like a bug in 0.7.3 (and 0.8.0). It's definitely recommended to upgrade to the latest stable release.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't upgrade to 0.10.0 and yes this does seem like a bug. Please see my workaround above.

Comment: What is stopping you from upgrading? Please report any issues on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem like a bug with pandas 0.7.3 or numpy 1.6. This only happens if the column being merged on is a date (internally converted to numpy.datetime64). My solution was to convert date into a string-

```
def _DatetimeToString(datetime64):
  timestamp = datetime64.astype(long)/1000000000
  return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

i = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('i.csv')
i = i.reset_index()
i['date'] = i['date'].map(_DatetimeToString)
e = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('e.csv')
e = e.reset_index()
i['date'] = i['date'].map(_DatetimeToString)

total_df = pd.merge(i, e, right_index=False, left_index=False,
                    right_on=['date'], left_on=['date'], how='left')
total_df = total_df.sort(column='date')
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue/bug came up for me as well. I was not merging on a datetime series, however, I did have a datetime series in the left dataframe. My solution was to de-dupe:

```
len(pophist)
```

2347

```
pop_merged = pd.merge(left=pophist, right=df_labels, how='left', 
             left_on ='candidate', right_on ='Slug', indicator = True)

pop_merged.shape
```

3303

```
pop_merged2 = pop_merged.drop_duplicates() #note dedupping is required due to issue in how pandas handles datetime dtypes on merge.  

len(pop_merged2)
```

2347