# Pandas creates duplicate index entries on merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

When merging data sets, I would expect pandas to not duplicate the values in the columns in the join. However, this does not appear to be the case.

Also, the multindex created from the join is stated as being unique, but a groupby suggests that it is not.

Is this the expected behaviour? How does one get around it to get the result I expect?

See below:

```
> pd.__version__

'0.13.1'

> merged_1 = pd.merge(left=A, right=B, how='outer', on=['date','x','y'])
> merged = pd.merge(left=merged_1, right=C, how='outer', on=['date','x','y'])

> merged.index.is_unique

True

> merged.dtypes # NB: same datatypes for corresponding columns in A,B & C

date             object
x                float64
y                object
...
dtype: object


> grp = merged.groupby(['date','x','y'])
> sizes = grp.size()
> sizes.sort(ascending=False)
> sizes[:4]

date              x      y
31/05/2014 08:26  2010   31/05/2014       2
18/05/2014 07:50  2010   14/06/2014       2
                         31/05/2014       2
                         30/05/2014       2
```

NB: I have tried testing this on smaller DataFrames to post here but I cant seem to replcate it when I do.

See [possible similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965036/dataframe-merge-creates-duplicate-records-in-pandas-0-7-3).

Comment: Sorry why do you think there are duplicates? the output display is showing a hierarchy, where there are empty rows, this shows the grouping so in the example you've shown I don't see any duplicates

Comment: I get the hierarchal index. The point is that there are "2"s in the value column of the group by size. Does this not indicate that the index for that row has been duplicated? I might be completely mistaken, I'm quite new to Pandas!

Comment: I can't say without data to reproduce your problem, it still could be correct but I can't sat from what you're showing